# bower install ends up with an error: Cannot call method 'split' of null

Tags: javascript, npm, bower

My component.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "path/to/main.css",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": null
  }
}
```

when i run 
$ bower install

I get:

bower error         Cannot call method 'split' of null

```
Stack trace:
TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of null
    at Object.json2decomposed (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-endpoint-parser/index.js:40:23)
    at Project._restoreNode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Project.js:704:35)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/object/forOwn.js:12:27
    at exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/object/forIn.js:57:19)
    at forIn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/object/forIn.js:38:17)
    at Object.forOwn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/object/forOwn.js:10:9)
    at Project._restoreNode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Project.js:702:17)
    at Project._analyse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Project.js:446:14)
    at Q.async (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:1126:30)
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:703:54)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` is not a valid value for a dependency. You have to specify a version.

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "1.10.2"
}
```

It can be approximate by specifying a [`semver` Range](https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver#ranges):

```
"jquery": "~1.10"
```

```
"jquery": "1.10.x"
```

Or, it can be set to `"latest"`, which will install `2.0.3`, currently:

```
"jquery": "latest"
```